# jQuery animate does not work(margin-left -200 to margin-left +200)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get some of my text to slide in from the left using .animate and it does not work.

**CSS**

```
.body #header > a {
    font-family: Georgia, Courier, Verdana;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 24px;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    margin-left: -200px;
        ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("body").ready(function () {
  $('#header a').animate({"margin-left": '+=200'});
```

---

Also, the HTML for linking the jQuery file I downloaded(works on slide, but only on normal .slide)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js\jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed your `.ready` function is firing?

Comment: Your code is working fine unless in your css .body refers to some element, which i have ignored. Make sure your jquery library is loaded properly. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/4LR4g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems with your code:

- Ready event should be bound on `document`, or use the `$(function)` syntax.
- `+=200` only animates from `-200` to `-200 + 200 = 0`, use either `200` or `+=400`
- src should be `js/jquery-1.9.1.js` - that is use forward slashes always in URI's

Thus

```
$(function () {
    $('#header a').animate({"margin-left": '+=400'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Worked. Looks like I have to work a lot to learn jQuery properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `$(document).ready` not `$("body").ready.

And the src should be `js/jquery-1.9.1.js` with the forward slash that urls use.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is wrong.  There is no .body element

```
#header > a {
    font-family: Georgia, Courier, Verdana;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 24px;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

And it should be $(document).ready

http://jsfiddle.net/RHHjf/

Comment: .body is a div I created.